# Sending S3 file as attachment to WhatsApp with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Currently we upload JPEG/PDF files to a S3 bucket.

These files are then *whatsapped* to others when a button is clicked (where *fileURL* represents the file location on the S3 bucket):

- When button is clicked from web:

`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${contactInfo.contactNumber}&text=${fileURL}`

- When button is clicked from mobile:

`whatsapp://send?phone=${contactInfo.contactNumber}&text=${fileURL}`

Result: *fileURL* is shown as text addressed to the contactNumber:
[image]
The item is clickable when 'send' is pressed:
[image]

My question is if it's possible to embed the *fileURL* as an **attachment** instead of an URL?

The app is developed with React. Thank you for reading

Comment: you are using a [simple send](https://whatsapp-for-business.firebaseapp.com/link-generator/en), that only support sending as text, no matter what you send, in order to be recognized as a media image, you need to bump up your send method and use [WhatsApp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media) for that

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I'm pretty new to the WhatsApp API document. May I know if it's available to everyone? Meaning are we free to use it even if we don't have a WhatsApp business account?